# Text overflow in textview in android

Tags: android, textview, overflow

How to make the text of `textview` to fill only the width and to start a new line in case the text overflow the width of the screen ?
I am trying to add the control from java code :

```
contentTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentTable);

            TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());       
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            row.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


            tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


            tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

            tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);


            tv1.setText(recipe.ingredients.get(i).name));
            tv2.setText(" "+recipe.ingredients.get(i).quantity);


            setTypeFace(tv1,tv2);

            row.addView(tv1);
            row.addView(tv2);

            contentTable.addView(row);
```

Comment: This should be the default behavior, please post the XML you are using so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_width="match_parent"` or specific dp width, `layout_height="wrap_content"` and that is it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The TableLayout `android:shrinkColumns` attribute allows to list the index of the columns to shrink (zero-based). It will remove unnecessary extra space from a column (considering all rows) and shrink it. It enables text wrapping to multi-line for the specified columns.

```
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="0,1" />
```